# Migration from a local POP PST to a email server

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, pop3, pst

I have a email account that has been going into a POP setup in Outlook 2010. I would like to re install Windows on my computer. The problem is that somehow, there are a few hundred emails that ARE in the POP setup in outlook but are NOT on the email server itself.

I would like to move those few hundred emails that are in the outlook PST but not on the server back onto the server so that I don't have to migrate the PST from the old install to the new one but will still keep the messed up emails.

Comment: Do you have an option to use IMAP? If you do, then perhaps you can connect Outlook using IMAP, and then copy the missing email from the local folder into the IMAP-connected folder and it will copy the email up into the server.

Comment: @Darius I can do IMAP but how can I move from the POP PST to the IMAP PST?

Comment: Moving it as answer as suggested.

Comment: @Darius make that your official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up IMAP on Outlook and Outlook will usually present it as if you have 2 different mailboxes (one for POP, one for IMAP).

When you set up the account on Outlook - make sure you label them properly (so you know which one is IMAP, which one is POP), and then simply drag and drop (or cut and paste) your email (or whole folders) from the POP side into the IMAP side.